# Why is the average of a sum equal the sum of the averages?

Tags: statistics, summation, average

I came across [this website](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-sums.htm) showing the proof of the above question in the Expected Value section. However, I do not quite understand why the probability of $xy$ becomes the probability of $x$ (or $y$) and why then the two summations reduce to only one in each term? Is it possible that $P_{xy}(x,y) = P_x(x) = P_y(y)$?

Comment: $\sum_y P_{XY}(x,y)=P_X(x)$ and $\sum_x P_{XY}(x,y)=P_Y(y)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \sum_x \sum_y x P_{XY}(x,y) = \sum_x \sum_y x \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_x \left( x \sum_y \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \right) \tag 1
\end{align}
The justification of the last step above is that as (lower-case) $y$ runs through the list of all possible values of (capital) $Y$, the index $x$ does not change.  It can therefore be pulled out.  Then we can say
\begin{align}
& \sum_y \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr\Big( (X=x\ \&\ Y=y_1) \text{ or }(X=x\ \&\ Y=y_2) \text{ or }(X=x\ \&\ Y=y_3)\text{ or }\cdots \Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr\Big( (X=x) \ \&\ (Y=y_1\text{ or }Y=y_2\text{ or }Y=y_3\text{ or } \cdots)\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Pr(X=x) \\[10pt]
= {} & P_X(x). 
\end{align}
Consequently $(1)$ becomes $\displaystyle \sum_x x P_X(x)$.

Comment: Actually, how is the second to last step true? I thought it was explained by X and Y being independent. Now I don't understand. Could you maybe show it in terms of Venn diagram?

Comment: The event $\Big( (X=x) \ \&\ (Y=y_1\text{ or }Y=y_2\text{ or }Y=y_3\text{ or } \cdots)\Big)$ is the same as the event $X=x$ provided $y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots$ is a complete list of the possible values of $Y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah I see. Since it is $X = x$ and $Y = [\text{full list}]$ just like employing males and males' skin color = [all shades], then it'll just be $X = x$ or, analogically, employees = males.